# How do I load custom image based datasets into Pytorch for use with a CNN?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have searched for hours on the internet to find a good solution to my issue. Here is some relevant background information to help you answer my question.

This is my first ever deep learning project and I have no idea what I am doing. I know the theory but not the practical elements.

The data that I am using can be found on kaggle at this link:
(https://www.kaggle.com/alxmamaev/flowers-recognition)

I am aiming to classify flowers based on the images provided in the dataset using a CNN.

Here is some sample code I have tried to use to load data in so far, this is my best attempt but as I mentioned I am clueless and Pytorch docs didn't offer much help that I could understand at my level.
(https://pastebin.com/fNLVW1UW)

```
    # Loads the images for use with the CNN.
def load_images(image_size=32, batch_size=64, root="../images"):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(32),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

    train_set = datasets.ImageFolder(root=root, train=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

    return train_loader


# Defining variables for use with the CNN.
classes = ('daisy', 'dandelion', 'rose', 'sunflower', 'tulip')
train_loader_data = load_images()

# Training samples.
n_training_samples = 3394
train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(np.arange(n_training_samples, dtype=np.int64))

# Validation samples.
n_val_samples = 424
val_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(np.arange(n_training_samples, n_training_samples + n_val_samples, dtype=np.int64))

# Test samples.
n_test_samples = 424
test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(np.arange(n_test_samples, dtype=np.int64))
```

Here are my direct questions that I require answers too:

- How do I fix my code to load in the dataset in an 80/10/10 split for training/test/validation?
- How do i create the required labels/classes for these images which are already divided by folders in /images ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at the data from Kaggle and your code, there are problems in your data loading.

The data should be in a different folder per class label for PyTorch `ImageFolder` to load it correctly. In your case, since all the training data is in the same folder, PyTorch is loading it as one train set. You can correct this by using a folder structure like - `train/daisy`, `train/dandelion`, `test/daisy`, `test/dandelion` and then passing the train and the test folder to the train and test `ImageFolder` respectively. Just change the folder structure and you should be good. Take a look at the official documentation of [`torchvision.datasets.Imagefolder`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder) which has a similar example.

---

As you said, these images which are already divided by folders in `/images`. PyTorch `ImageFolder` assumes that images are organized in the following way. But this folder structure is only correct if you are using all the images for train set:

````
```
/images/daisy/100080576_f52e8ee070_n.jpg
/images/daisy/10140303196_b88d3d6cec.jpg
.
.
.
/images/dandelion/10043234166_e6dd915111_n.jpg
/images/dandelion/10200780773_c6051a7d71_n.jpg
```
````

where 'daisy', 'dandelion' etc. are class labels.

The correct folder structure if you want to split the dataset into train and test set in your case (note that I know you want to split the dataset into train, validation, and test set, but it doesn't matters as this is just an example to get the idea out):

````
```
/images/train/daisy/100080576_f52e8ee070_n.jpg
/images/train/daisy/10140303196_b88d3d6cec.jpg
.
.
/images/train/dandelion/10043234166_e6dd915111_n.jpg
/images/train/dandelion/10200780773_c6051a7d71_n.jpg
.
.
/images/test/daisy/300080576_f52e8ee070_n.jpg
/images/test/daisy/95140303196_b88d3d6cec.jpg
.
.
/images/test/dandelion/32143234166_e6dd915111_n.jpg
/images/test/dandelion/65200780773_c6051a7d71_n.jpg
```
````

Then, you can refer to the following full code example on how to write a dataloader:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.utils.data as data
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 10
LEARNING_RATE = 0.003
TRAIN_DATA_PATH = "./images/train/"
TEST_DATA_PATH = "./images/test/"
TRANSFORM_IMG = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(256),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225] )
    ])

train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=TRAIN_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
train_data_loader = data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True,  num_workers=4)
test_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=TEST_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
test_data_loader  = data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=4) 

class CNN(nn.Module):
    # omitted...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Number of train samples: ", len(train_data))
    print("Number of test samples: ", len(test_data))
    print("Detected Classes are: ", train_data.class_to_idx) # classes are detected by folder structure

    model = CNN()    
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()    

    # Training and Testing
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):        
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_data_loader):
            b_x = Variable(x)   # batch x (image)
            b_y = Variable(y)   # batch y (target)
            output = model(b_x)[0]          
            loss = loss_func(output, b_y)   
            optimizer.zero_grad()           
            loss.backward()                 
            optimizer.step()

            if step % 50 == 0:
                test_x = Variable(test_data_loader)
                test_output, last_layer = model(test_x)
                pred_y = torch.max(test_output, 1)[1].data.squeeze()
                accuracy = sum(pred_y == test_y) / float(test_y.size(0))
                print('Epoch: ', epoch, '| train loss: %.4f' % loss.data[0], '| test accuracy: %.2f' % accuracy)
```

Comment: Awesome. This helped so much. I got it to work by doing what you suggested. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: I changed my code up but now I am getting weird results when I run the program.Epoch 1, Train Accuracy: 0 , TrainLoss: 0.1286807805299759 , Test Accuracy: 0
Epoch 2, Train Accuracy: 0 , TrainLoss: 0.12216705083847046 , Test Accuracy: 0

Answer (score 1):

There now exists an easy package for the splitting, called 'split-folders'. See [here](https://pypi.org/project/split-folders/). 
E.g.

```
import splitfolders
splitfolders.ratio(image_path, output="output", seed=43, ratio=(.8,.1,.1))
```